# Access to my Facebook application from phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, facebook, cordova

when I register my Facebook application I asked for Website URL. That means that only users from that URL can be access to Facebook API. But I don't need it.

I'm made a mobile application by phonegap, I used ionic (HTML5 mobile framework).

I made an initialize to Facebook SDK in my javascript files, and tried to access to the api. Well it didn't work becuase the hostname on mobile application is `''` (none, nothing, empty string), there is no hostname/URL parameter on mobile application.

When I tried it on my computer it worked when I put in Facebook application settings this website URL: `http://localhost/`, and it's worked becuase i really was on `localhost`.

How should I fix it, so I could access to my application from every URL and not only the URL I asked in the application settings?

Sample of my javascript code: (Written with angular.js)

```
$scope.loginFB = function() {
        Facebook.login(function(loginResponse) {
            if(loginResponse.status == 'connected') {
                $rootScope.$storage.local.userLoggedIn = true;
                Facebook.api('/me', function(facebookUser) {
                    $rootScope.$storage.local.currentUser = facebookUser;
                });
            }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look to [sociogram sample on github](https://github.com/ccoenraets/sociogram-angular-ionic)
 , a sample application demonstrating how to integrate with Facebook in your Angular/Ionic apps

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mobile application, you should integrate with facebook mobile sdk for android and ios. 
See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

There are several cordova plugins that can help you with such integration (I am the author of one by the way). You can search for these plugins at http://plugreg.com/search?q=facebook

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used [Facebook connect](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) plugin and for ionic framework you can also try [ngCordova Facebook](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Facebook)